# Pandas: Remove Items who has less than 2 non-zero values

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration, rows

I have a dataframe having consecutive 30 weekly date for all 317 different ProductCode and also Weekly Sales Quantity columns like on below:

```
Date    ProductCode Weekly_Units_Sold
2015-08-09   1       46.0
2015-08-09   2       46.0
2015-08-09   3       31.0
 ...         ...      ...
2015-08-09   317     47.0
2015-08-16   1       0
2015-08-16   2       46.0
2015-08-16   3       31.0
  ...       ...
2015-08-16  317      75.0
2015-08-23   1       0.0
2015-08-23   2       90.0
2015-08-23   3       175.0
....         ...   
2015-08-23  317      20.0
 ....      ...       ..
2015-12-27   1       0.0
2015-12-27   2       30.0
2015-12-27   3       150.0
....         ...   
2015-12-27  317      20.0
```

I am trying to check Weekly_Units_Sold of each ProductCode and if is there any ProductCode which has less than 2 non-Zero values in Weekly_Units_Sold; the code should be remove all rows belonging to detected ProductCode.

Let's say ProductCode 1 has been detected has only 1 non-zero in Weekly_Units_Sold Column values and its 29 other values are all 0 . Want to Delete all the 30 rows belonging to ProductCode 1 from dataframe,

```
Date    ProductCode Weekly_Units_Sold
2015-08-09   2       46.0
2015-08-09   3       31.0
 ...         ...      ...
2015-08-09   317     47.0
2015-08-16   2       46.0
2015-08-16   3       31.0
  ...       ...
2015-08-16  317      75.0
2015-08-23   2       90.0
2015-08-23   3       175.0
....         ...   
2015-08-23  317      20.0
 ....      ...       ..
2015-12-27   2       30.0
2015-12-27   3       150.0
....         ...   
2015-12-27  317      20.0
```

What is the best Pythonistic way to do tihs?
Thanks!

Comment: Please share the expected output based on sample input.

Comment: Please add it in the question itself. Not in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your sample data a bit so I could build a working example.

```
Date    ProductCode Weekly_Units_Sold
2015-08-09   1       46.0
2015-08-09   2       46.0
2015-08-09   3       31.0
2015-08-09   317     47.0
2015-08-16   1       0
2015-08-16   2       46.0
2015-08-16   3       31.0
2015-08-16  317      75.0
2015-08-23   1       0.0
2015-08-23   2       90.0
2015-08-23   3       175.0
2015-08-23  317      20.0
2015-12-27   1       0.0
2015-12-27   2       30.0
2015-12-27   3       150.0
2015-12-27  317      20.0
```

Here we begin with pd.read_clipboard() on the above data.

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

print(df)

Date    ProductCode Weekly_Units_Sold
0   2015-08-09  1   46.0
1   2015-08-09  2   46.0
2   2015-08-09  3   31.0
3   2015-08-09  317 47.0
4   2015-08-16  1   0.0
5   2015-08-16  2   46.0
6   2015-08-16  3   31.0
7   2015-08-16  317 75.0
8   2015-08-23  1   0.0
9   2015-08-23  2   90.0
10  2015-08-23  3   175.0
11  2015-08-23  317 20.0
12  2015-12-27  1   0.0
13  2015-12-27  2   30.0
14  2015-12-27  3   150.0
15  2015-12-27  317 20.0
```

We group by ProductCode and and create string lists of all the Weekly_Units_Sold values in the Weekly_Units_Sold column.

```
df_gb = df.groupby(['ProductCode'])['Weekly_Units_Sold'].apply(list).to_frame()

print(df_gb)
            Weekly_Units_Sold
ProductCode 
1           [46.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
2           [46.0, 46.0, 90.0, 30.0]
3           [31.0, 31.0, 175.0, 150.0]
317         [47.0, 75.0, 20.0, 20.0]
```

Next we can use a lambda and np.count_nonzero to give us boolean values for product codes with < 2 non-zero values.

```
df_gb['non_zero_lt_two'] = df_gb['Weekly_Units_Sold'].apply(lambda x: True if np.count_nonzero(np.array(x)) < 2 else False)
```

print(df_gb)

```
        Weekly_Units_Sold           non_zero_lt_two
ProductCode     
1       [46.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]       True
2       [46.0, 46.0, 90.0, 30.0]    False
3       [31.0, 31.0, 175.0, 150.0]  False
317     [47.0, 75.0, 20.0, 20.0]    False
```

We can then turn the True value rows into a list.

```
prod_code_list = df_gb.index[df_gb['non_zero_lt_two'] == True].tolist()
```

And then finally remove the desired rows from the original df.

```
df = df[~df['ProductCode'].isin(prod_code_list)]

print(df)

Date    ProductCode Weekly_Units_Sold
1   2015-08-09  2   46.0
2   2015-08-09  3   31.0
3   2015-08-09  317 47.0
5   2015-08-16  2   46.0
6   2015-08-16  3   31.0
7   2015-08-16  317 75.0
9   2015-08-23  2   90.0
10  2015-08-23  3   175.0
11  2015-08-23  317 20.0
13  2015-12-27  2   30.0
14  2015-12-27  3   150.0
15  2015-12-27  317 20.0
```

Comment: Thanks its perfect. Could you advice me a resource to improve myself on this kind of process?

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Beyond Stack Overflow, These are good places to start: https://medium.com/dunder-data/minimally-sufficient-pandas-a8e67f2a2428, https://chrisalbon.com/